# How can I create buttons connected by a horizontal line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, haml

I have a Ruby on Rails web application. For the front end, I'm using haml and sass. So, basically, I have a series of buttons, and I want to create a straight line that goes across them. I tried positioning a div behind the buttons and using the bottom border to achieve the line, but getting it to line up perfectly with the center of the buttons was very difficult.

Here's my haml:

```
 .stepwizard
     .stepwizard__row
      .stepwizard__step
       %a.btn.stepwizard__btn{ href: "#", title: 'Choose Payment',class: stepwizard_active_class(active, 'payment') } 1
       %p.stepwizard__step-text Payment
  .stepwizard__step
       %a.btn.stepwizard__btn{ href: "#", title: 'Delivery Options', class: stepwizard_active_class(active, 'delivery') } 2
       %p.stepwizard__step-text Delivery 
 .stepwizard__step
       %a.btn.stepwizard__btn{ href: "#", title: 'Billing Info', class: stepwizard_active_class(active, 'billing') } 3
       %p.stepwizard__step-text Billing 
.stepwizard__step
      %a.btn.stepwizard__btn{ href: "#", title: 'Summary', class: stepwizard_active_class(active, 'summary') } 4
      %p.stepwizard__step-text Summary
```

and scss:

```
   .stepwizard {
     background: #005DFF;
     padding: 40px 50px 40px;

    &__row {
     display: flex;
     width: 100%;
     justify-content: space-between;
     position: relative;

     &:before {
        top: 14px;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        content: " ";
        width: 100%;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: #005DFF;
        z-order: 0;
           }
         }
        &__step {
          text-align: center;
          position: relative;
          button[disabled] {
            opacity: 1 !important;
            filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
              }
          }
        &__step-text {
           margin-top: 10px;
           position: absolute;
           color: white;
           min-width: 110px;
           left: 50%;
           top: 30px;
           transform: translateX(-50%);
        }
        &__btn {
          width: 30px;
          height: 30px;
          color: #005DFF;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 6px 0;
          font-size: 12px;
          line-height: 1.428571429;
          border-radius: 15px;
            }
          }
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a sudo code, I believe you were looking something like this.
Key point are

- Line Div should be before buttons group div with a `position: absolute`
- buttons group div can be `position:relative` or absolute(in case of absolute you might have to adjust z-index)
- Lastly a container div with `position: relative` so that even absolute div remains within it.

**hope this helps**

```
:css
  .buttons_inline{
    position: relative;    
  }
  .back_line{
    background-color: coral;
    height:2px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:50%;
  }
  .contain{
    position:relative;
    background-color: lightgray;
    text-align:center;
  }
.contain
  .back_line
  .buttons_inline
    %button button 1
    %button button 2
    %button button 3
    %button button 4
```